# Can H2O be used with node.js (standalone/offline in Electron app)

Tags: node.js, electron, h2o, node-java

Does h2o-3 have node.js bindings? I found https://github.com/h2oai/h2o.js but when I saw no updates in two years I realized it was for h2o v2.

I'm specifically asking about deploying a POJO/MOJO jar file, in the context of an Electron app. I.e. offline, not using the REST API to communicate back to a server.  (Maybe my question is more: could I use the h2o.jar, and a pojo/mojo file, with something like https://github.com/joeferner/node-java and expect everything to work together, across each of Linux/Mac/Windows?)

FWIW, TensorFlow integration seems vapourware at the moment: https://github.com/node-tensorflow/node-tensorflow, but MxNet seems to have something working: https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet.js/   So, if H2O pojo/mojo can be used from within node.js apps, could Deep Water models also work?

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but this project seems promising.  https://github.com/joeferner/node-java

Answer (score 1):

H2O does not have node.js bindings, but H2O exposes a well documented REST API. From Electron, you can start H2O using the `child_process` module, then talk to H2O using the REST API. If you only care about embedding the model in your Electron app, you can self host the model in a java process using node-java (if you are building some kind of a desktop-only application), OR you can have the Electron app talk to a local or remote http server that hosts the model (see https://github.com/h2oai/app-consumer-loan)